# Rearrange the rows of the given matrix so that arrange them in descending order of the sum of their negative pairs

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The task was to rearrange the rows of a given matrix in the created matrix so that
arrange them in descending order of the sum of their negative pairs (as i mentioned in the title)

Here is what i tried:

```
import numpy as np
import random

rows = int(input('\nInput the number of rows: '))
cols = int(input('Input the number of cols: '))


def AutoFill(rows, cols):
    rand_arr = []
    for k in range(rows):
        arr = []
        for v in range(cols):
            a = random.randint(-5, 5)
            arr.append(a)
        rand_arr.append(np.array(arr))
    return np.array(rand_arr)

arr = AutoFill(rows, cols)
PrintArr(arr)


def Rearrange(arr, rows, cols):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, rows+1):
        if (arr[i] < 0) and (arr[i] % 2 == 0):
            sum += arr[i]
```

When i tried to run i've got an error:

```
    if (arr[i] < 0) and (arr[i] % 2 == 0):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use 
a.any() or a.all()
```

I'll be very grateful for your help

Comment: I did not get any error tested by `rows`=10 and `cols=15` and changing `PrintArr(arr)` to print(arr).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I get no error when I run you code except I has to change "PrintArr(arr)" to "print(arr)"

Comment: @C.Pappy run, e.g. `Rearrange(arr, 1, 1)`

Comment: @Ali_Sh ^^^^^^^

Comment: Can you please explain "negative pairs"?

Comment: @C.Pappy, sorry, i forgot to add `Rearrange(arr, rows, cols)`

You need to rearrange the rows of the matrix so that in the first place was the row with the largest sum of negative even elements, in the last place - the row with the smallest sum of negative even elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: larger test case: 4x4 matrix

If I understand the proglem, this code should andwer your question:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def AutoFill(rows, cols):
    rand_arr = []
    for k in range(rows):
        arr = []
        for v in range(cols):
            a = random.randint(-5, 5)
            arr.append(a)
        rand_arr.append(np.array(arr))
    return np.array(rand_arr)

def reducer(row):
    # Return the value calculated as pwe the "negative pairs" specification
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i%2 == 0 and row[i] < 0:
            total += row[i]
    return -total  # NOTE the negative sign. It contols the row order.

def Rearrange(arr):
    #  Return the array sorted by the desired "value" of each row.
    return np.array(sorted(arr, key=lambda row: reducer(row)))

#rows = int(input('\nInput the number of rows: '))
#cols = int(input('Input the number of cols: '))

# So that we get repeatable results
random.seed(2)
rows = 4
cols = 4
arr = AutoFill(rows, cols)
print(arr)
print(Rearrange(arr))
```

Output:

```
[[-5 -4 -4  0]
 [-3  5 -1 -1]
 [ 4 -2  4 -5]
 [ 4  5 -3  1]]
[[-5 -4 -4  0]
 [-3  5 -1 -1]
 [ 4  5 -3  1]
 [ 4 -2  4 -5]]
```